# C# - Parse anonymous type to int32

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having problems when trying to parse values that I retrieve from an XML-file. I get several values stored `toList()` in a variable `var` and I want to convert them to `Int32` and summarize them. Here is the method I am using:

```
public void ViktTjurar()
{
    string år = TextBoxÅr.Text;
    int test= 0;
    int summa = 0;
    XElement vikt =  XElement.Load(path);


    var vikttjurar = (from h in vikt.Descendants("älgrapport")
                      where (string)h.Element("år") == år && (string)
                      h.Element("typ") == "Tjur"
                      select new
                      {
                          tvikt = int.Parse(h.Element("Vikt").Value),

                      }).ToList();

    //List<int> vikter1 = new List<int>();
    foreach (var e in vikttjurar)
    {
        test = Convert.ToInt32(e);                             
    }
}
```

At the moment I get 3 values from the XML-file, stored in `var vikttjurar` and I thought I parsed them correctly with: `tvikt = int.Parse(h.Element("Vikt").Value)`.

It seems it doesn't work. When assigning the value of `e` to `test` (in a `foreach` loop) I get error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'

So I tried to `Convert` `e` to `Int32` (as you can see in my code above) but that wont work either and I get the same error: `System.InvalidCastException`.

Does anyone know how to solve the parsing from anonymous type to `int` or, even better, parse AND summarize the values in `var vikttjurar`?

Comment: You almost certainly just shouldn't be using an anonymous type at all.  Just select the int value directly rather than wrapping it in an anonymous type that you then need to just unwrap.

Comment: By the way, you really shouldn't use non-ascii characters in your variable names etc.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I've seen this advice a few times, but never any justification... Any more to say on the matter?

Comment: What if your new coworker decides to use an english keyboard because most programmers prefer that? He won't be able to enter those characters easily.

Comment: Yeah this is just for an assignment at uni so no one but my teacher will have to deal with my messy code :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Agreed, but the anglo-centric view of programming must grate a little on non-English speaking users!

Comment: I'm German and tell everyone who uses non-English identifiers to stop it...

Comment: Yes, although I don't like English-centrism, it's a fact that needs to be accepted, that English is a well established and common language in programming. Using diacritics is thus a bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

You've already done the conversion in your linq statement, and created anonymous objects with a single property, `tvikt`. Now you just need to look it up:

```
    foreach (var e in vikttjurar)
    {

        test = e.tvikt;

    }
```

BTW, the `XElement` type supports [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Int32` (or `int`), so in your Linq statement, you can:

```
...select new
{
    tvikt = (int)h.Element("Vikt"),

}...
```

Comment: Use "mark as answer" - the checkmark button - to celebrate properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this, you have the `int` parsed already:

```
test = e.tvikt;
```

Also, you could simplify your whole code a bit:

```
var vikttjurar = (from h in vikt.Descendants("älgrapport")
                  where (string)h.Element("år") == år && (string)
                  h.Element("typ") == "Tjur"
                  select int.Parse(h.Element("Vikt").Value))
                 .ToList();

//List<int> vikter1 = new List<int>();
foreach (var e in vikttjurar)
{
    test = e; // e is an int here
}
```

Comment: Thank you som much! :) This problem took me all day and hundreds of trials and errors. Thanks again!